# How to make use of variables in Wildfly configuration file?

Tags: server, environment-variables, wildfly, devops, wildfly-10

I am setting up a common `standalone-full.xml` file for all server environments, and therefore need to have variables for database URL's (and such), instead of hard coding them.

One such section in the configuration file might look like this:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/somename" pool-name="somename" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${SOMENAME_DB_URL}</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>${DB_USERNAME}</user-name>
                    <password>${DB_PASSWORD}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

However, upon starting the server with this config file it simply throws an "Unable to resolve expression" error for all such sections.

I've tried putting the variables in `/etc/environment`, as well as in the `.jbossclirc` file in `/bin` using `set DB_USERNAME=mydbusername`, but to no avail.

As you can see I'm fumbling a bit in the dark here since I haven't been able to find any proper documentation on how to do this. I'm not even sure if it's actually possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The WildFly 10 documentation you're searching for: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Java system properties instead of environment variables.

You can also pass these properties as `-D` arguments to `standalone.sh`, e.g.

```
bin/standalone.sh -DDB_USERNAME=me -DDB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Alternatively, you can define your properties in a properties file and pass that to the startup script with a `-P` option:

```
bin/standalone.sh -P database.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Does overriding standard properties from Wildfly work that way?
For example `jboss.http.port` from `standalone.xml`

```
   <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

One possibilty is to call `standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=8081`. Then, Wildfly http port should be on `8081`.

It should also work for your own variables.